# Is importance of ease of first use a recognized UX concept?

Tags: usability, conversion, first-impression, ease-of-use

This is a bit strange question. I was wondering is there a named concept that ease of first use/trial is critical for winning new users and conversion. I'm referring to products/apps/services rather than websites and the aspect how fast and easy it is to try something and see value. I wanted to learn more about this but all I found was about websites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, often called "First Time User Experience (FTUE)", "Out of Box Experience (OOBE)" or "Unboxing".

There's lots of good articles out there depending on whether you're developing a  website, mobile app or something else.

Some good first guidelines are:

1. Give users a clear path forward
2. Instill confidence
3. Delight the user
4. Less thinking, more doing
5. Teach users how to learn

From "UX Means Love at First Run" [1]

Here are some links I had bookmarked (I'm currently looking at a FTUE for one of our products. :)

[1] http://franklyspeakingnews.com/2012/04/ux-means-love-at-first-run/
https://blog.intercom.io/designing-first-run-experiences-to-delight-users/
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/04/rethinking-mobile-tutorials-which-patterns-really-work/
http://www.kryshiggins.com/first-time-user-experiences-in-mobile-apps/
http://www.hcde.washington.edu/files/moya_ppt_creating_great_first_impressions.pdf

Relevant SE link: [Are there any resources/guidelines on First Time User Experience?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/10067/are-there-any-resources-guidelines-on-first-time-user-experience?rq=1)

Comment: Great, thanks! That is what I was looking for. OOBE is a good name by the way.

Comment: These are good, though I'd say the term 'unboxing' has less to do with the UX of the product itself and more to do with the UX of the packaging.

Comment: Other common labels: learnability and on-boarding.